fluttterfire configure Failed to parse JSON response from Firebase CLI
I'm trying to connect my flutter application to firebase and I see that I can implement this by using the flutterfire CLI.
I started by installing firebase CLI by using:
npm install -g firebase-tools

Then I installed the flutterfire CLI with
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

Everything was good until I tried:
flutterfire configure

With this command, I encountered this error:

I'm using latest version for node.js (v22.12.0) and for firebase (13.29.1)
and the version I use for flutterfire is 1.0.0.
I tried flutterfire 1.0.1-dev.4 but can't list my projects and get the same error

There seems to be some text ("Active code page: 1252") in from of the JSON response, which makes that response not valid JSON. It looks like this happens when flutterfire calls the firebase command to get a list of projects. You might want to see if you can reproduce this output with just the firebase command, and if so: file an issue on the GitHub repo for that project (as the output is not valid JSON).

The FlutterFire CLI tool internally calls out to the Firebase CLI (to get a list of projects, in your case) and expects a JSON response. Somehow the output in your case has an extra line in front of it:

Active code page: 1252

I tried to reproduce the output, but when I run this command on Firebase CLI version 13.29.1 (the latest version as of this writing):
% firebase --version
13.29.1
% firebase projects:list --json

I get this output:
✔ Preparing the list of your Firebase projects
{
  "status": "success",
  "result": [
    {
      "projectId": "basegv-e9065",
      "projectNumber": "312648983577",
      "displayName": "basegv",
      "name": "projects/basegv-e9065",
      "resources": {
        "hostingSite": "basegv-e9065"
      },
      "state": "ACTIVE",
      "etag": "1_42703802-0149-45b1-9264-7b9b9434f0b1"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

Note that this does not include the extra line that you get (and which makes the output invalid JSON). Unfortunately I don't see in the code of the Firebase CLI where this output may come from.
You'll want to see if you can reproduce the output, and if so, file a bug on either the Firebase CLI repo or the FlutterFire CLI repo.
Note that the issue was also posted on /r/Firebase a couple of months ago, so it seems to not be new (and thus likely only happens to a subset of the users of these tools).
